# Model relations not recognized in Yii2

Tags: model, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have 2 models created called User and ReferralsForm where Users is the parent and ReferralsForm is the child. There are two foreign keys I am assigning to ReferralsForm from Users but with different names. I am using Gii to generate my models along with the relations. Here is the structure:

```
User
------------
users_id(PK),
display_name,
username,
email,
password,
member_since,
referral_hash

ReferralsForm
-------------
referral_id(PK),
userid(FK),
referred_user_id(FK),
status
```

User Model Relation code and attributelables

```
public function getReferrals()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ReferralsForm::className(), ['userid' => 'user_id']);
}

public function getReferrals0()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ReferralsForm::className(), ['referred_user_id' => 'user_id']);
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'user_id' => 'Userid',
        'username' => 'Username',
        'email' => 'Email',
        'display_name' => 'Display Name',
        'password' => 'Password',
        'member_since' => 'Member Since',
        'auth_key' => 'Auth Key',
        'referral_hash' => 'Referral Hash',
    ];
}
```

ReferralsForm Model Relation code and attributelabels

```
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['user_id' => 'userid']);
}

public function getReferredUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['user_id' => 'referred_user_id']);
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'userid' => 'Userid',
        'referred_user_id' => 'Referred User ID',
        'subscription_id' => 'Subscription ID',
        'status' => 'Status',
    ];
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function actionReferrals()
{
    $query = User::find()->joinWith('ReferralsForm');

    $model = new User();
    $ref_hash = $model->getHash();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);  
    return $this->render('referrals' ,['dataProvider' => $dataProvider, 'ref_hash' => $ref_hash]);
}
```

Still it gives me an error

```
Invalid Argument – yii\base\InvalidArgumentException
app\models\User has no relation named "ReferralsForm".

Caused by: Unknown Method – yii\base\UnknownMethodException
Calling unknown method: app\models\User::getReferralsForm()
```

Comment: seems you have a type in your User table  or in yoru relation  users_id and  user_id ..

Comment: Let me update my question and add the attributelabels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a relation name referrals (getReferrals() )  you should use referrals  in your joinWith

```
$query = User::find()->joinWith('referrals');
```

Comment: I do have a relation called referrals in the database side. I thought the raw tables from the database is already discarded and that you should use the models instead. It's working now thank you!

Comment: You mean a view  in database  ?? .. or a foreignKey  ?  .. anyway  Yii2 use the function provided  as getter in model with hasMany(  .) or hasOne()   as  relation  ..  ..

Comment: I just realized that it gets the returned value of the function tablename() for the `joinWith` statement that is why it has to be `referrals` since it's the returned value of the tablename() function... *facepalm